# ASP.NET MVC Display Output on same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm currently doing some testing with a form. I'm trying to get the selected value to be displayed on the same page once submit is clicked. So if submit is clicked the value selected will display directly under. But currently when submit is clicked, I will be guided to a blank page with the selected value being displayed. How do I make so that the output would be displayed on the same page?

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PAM_Dashboard_Project.Models
{
    public class Vaults
    {
         public string Envs { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Envs
    {
         RTPprod,
         OMA,
         BG1,
         BG2,
         Cloud,
         Workstation,
         QA
    }
}
```

View:

```
<form asp-controller="CyberArk" asp-action="CyberArk" method="post" role="form" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to carry out this action?');" id="form1" style="display:none;">
  @* Form 1 *@
  <form asp-controller="CyberArk" asp-action="CyberArk" method="post" role="form" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to carry out this action?');" id="form1" style="display:none;">
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="font-size:15px;">
                            Vault Status
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <p>  This script returns status of vault servers for the chosen environment. It is used to determine if any servers overlap in order to detect a split brain.</p>
                            </div>
                            @model PAM_Dashboard_Project.Models.Vaults
                            @Html.DropDownList("Envs", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Envs))), "Select Enivronment", new { @class = "form-control" })





                            &nbsp;
                            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PAM_Dashboard_Project.Models;

namespace PAM_Dashboard_Project.Controllers
{
    public class CyberArkController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult CyberArk()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string CyberArk(Vaults newVault)
        {
             string SelectedValue = newVault.Envs;
             return(SelectedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the `[Post]` action you should replace the `return` with `return View(newVault)` to return the same page.

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak I just tried that, and it causes an error due to it being a string

Comment: You need to change your form post to an ajax post.  A form post will navigate away from the page to a new page (or at least reload the same page).  An ajax post will stay on the same page and then let you display your results after the post is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller my friend:

```
public class Vaults
{
    public string Envs { get; set; }
}

public enum Envs
{
    RTPprod,
    OMA,
    BG1,
    BG2,
    Cloud,
    Workstation,
    QA
}

public class PassValue
{
    public string passValue { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Tut112(PassValue passVal)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            RetVal = passVal.passValue
        }
        , @"application/json");
    }

    public ActionResult Tut112()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Your View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut112</title>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#ajaxButton").click(function () {
                var SendData = { passValue: $("#passValue").val() };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Home/Tut112',
                    data: SendData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#stackDataHere").append('<div>' + data.RetVal + "</div>");
                    }
                });
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @*<form asp-controller="CyberArk" asp-action="CyberArk" method="post" role="form"
        onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to carry out this action?');" id="form1" style="display:none;">*@
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @* Form 1 *@
        @*<form asp-controller="CyberArk" asp-action="CyberArk" method="post" role="form"
            onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to carry out this action?');" id="form1" style="display:none;">*@
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="font-size:15px;">
                                Vault Status
                            </a>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <p>  This script returns status of vault servers for the chosen environment. It is used to determine if any servers overlap in order to detect a split brain.</p>
                                </div>
                                @model Testy20161006.Controllers.Vaults
                                @Html.DropDownList("Envs", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Testy20161006.Controllers.Envs))), "Select Enivronment", new { id = "passValue", @class = "form-control" })
                                &nbsp;
                                @*<button type="submit">Submit</button>*@
                                <input type="button" id="ajaxButton" value="Submit" />
                                &nbsp;
                                <div id="stackDataHere"></div>
                            </div>
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @*</form>*@
        }
        @*</form>*@
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BB956 can you please tell me if you want me to help you put the selections in fields, so you can post back -and/or- help you to do this solution in angular or knockout?